# Unity Animator queued animation from different animators on different objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's been 3 days since I started searching for a way to make two animations of different objects execute in sequence.

I am building a card game, and every card has a different Animator.

It's a single player game, so I make the player play versus a scripted AI.

I want card A to do `animationA1`. After this is completed, I want it to do `animationA2`. After those two are executed, I want card B to do `animationB1`.

What I'm asking is, how can I make different Animators on different objects interact and wait for each other? I'm using C# for scripting!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You really have a few different ways you might be able to do this. I know nothing about your architecture, which makes it rather difficult.

One possibility is to use events, and execute them as part of your animations. That way they can subscribe to eachother (preferably, their owner does the subscribing between them).

You might also do it with simple callback delegates. Perhaps have a parameter of type `Action` on your animations, which defaults to `null`.

Those are the simplest ways, since you can have the mechanism that ends your animations execute the event/delegate. Generally speaking, if this is exposed to other programmers (if you were making an engine) events would be preferable. However, for your case this seems unlikely, and you seem to want handling to be per method. In that case, the second option may be better.

You may need to do some additional research to implement these, but you will definitely learn a lot about C# and programming in general in doing so.